# Issue while adding duplicate values to array in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a 10(or n) checkboxes in my view. Now I was trying to get the name and age of the checked checkbox.

I could get the name and age of the employee of a checkbox is checked. However, If I encounter duplicate age from then age values are not appending to the list.

How we can add ages and names to different lists which allows duplicate items.

My code snippet is here: http://jsbin.com/yitosopafo/6/edit?html,js,output

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('checkBoxController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.employees=[{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}];
  $scope.selection=[];
        $scope.ages=[];
  //toggle selection for a given employee by name
  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(employeeName,employeeAge) {
     var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(employeeName);
          $scope.id=idx;
     // is currently selected
     if (idx > -1) {
       $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
          $scope.ages.splice(idx, 1);
     }
     // is newly selected
     else {
       $scope.selection.push(employeeName);
          $scope.ages.push(employeeAge);
     }
   };
      
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="checkBoxController">

  
  <div ng-repeat="employee in employees">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(employee.name,employee.age)" />
    {{employee.name}}

  </div>
  
  <p>Names</p>
  <div ng-repeat="name in selection" class="selected-item">
  {{name}}
  </div>
 
  <p>Ages</p>
  <div ng-repeat="age in ages" class="selected-item">
  {{age}}
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Balu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple answer is to use track by $index for repeating duplicate value.

Read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

look for Tracking and Duplicates

```
<p>Ages</p>
  <div ng-repeat="age in ages track by $index" class="selected-item">
        {{age}}
        </div>
```

Snippet

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('checkBoxController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.employeeDetails = [];
  $scope.employees=[{name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
       {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
       {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}];
  $scope.selection=[];
        $scope.ages=[];
  //toggle selection for a given employee by name
  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(employeeName,employeeAge) {
     var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(employeeName);
          $scope.id=idx;
     // is currently selected
     if (idx > -1) {
       $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
          $scope.ages.splice(idx, 1);
     }
     // is newly selected
     else {
       $scope.selection.push(employeeName);
          $scope.ages.push(employeeAge);
     }
        
        var obj = {};
      obj[employeeName] = employeeAge ;
     
                 if(angular.element(event.target).attr("checked")=== "checked")
    {
      $scope.employeeDetails.push(obj);
    }
    else
    {
      
 $scope.employeeDetails.map(function(e,ind) {
        
        if(JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify(obj) )
        {
           $scope.employeeDetails.splice(ind, 1);  

        }
        });
      
      
     }
      
   };
     
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="checkBoxController">

  
  <div ng-repeat="employee in employees">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(employee.name,employee.age)" />
    {{employee.name}}

  </div>
  
  <p>Names</p>
  <div ng-repeat="name in selection track by $index" class="selected-item">
  {{name}}
  </div>
 
  <p>Ages</p>
  <div ng-repeat="age in ages track by $index" class="selected-item">
  {{age}}
  </div>
   <div data-ng-if="employeeDetails.length > 0">
    <p>JSON Object</p>
     {{employeeDetails}}
   </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Deep. Thank you. If I use track by option, I can display the values. However,I have to use name and age of the selected check boxes in my ASP.NET.Can you please help me how to get name and as key value pair

Comment: do you meant name and age as key value ?  i.e. {"john":"25"}

Comment: Update the snippet for the same, hope this will help you. at the end i am displaying the JSON object created on selecting the checkbox.

Comment: Hi Deep,Your solution works perfect.However,though I uncheck any check box,the value is adding to JSON object and If I type uncheck the same option the value is adding twice.

Comment: Hi Deep, Now it working as expected. Thak you for your help